# filter() logic misunderstanding

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering why this logic doesn't work when using the filter() function:

```
def remove_negatives(list_1):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x < 0 == False, list_1))
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to remove all the negative numbers from a given list, now...What I don't understand is why this is not returning the new list with all the negative numbers removed, but instead is returning the list of all the negative numbers. I thought that basically what it is saying is that, return the value if x < 0 is False, so basically saying return the value if x is not smaller than 0, but why doesn't this work? Did I do something wrong? Oh and I also know how to make this work I have two ways that make this work but I'm just curious as to what causes this perticular logic to fail.

Comment: Why not just `x >= 0`?

Comment: Or rather, ```x>0```? Ah, you changed it. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand that works and also x >= 0 but Im just curious as to why the method that i mentioned doesn't return the output I expected, what causes the output to not return what is expected but instead return all the negative numbers.

Answer (score -2):

You are using

```
x < 0 == False
```

Which is True for all negative numbers because it is doing the comparison first

0 is Logically the same as False, Positive numbers are logically the same as True.

Firstly, the `0 == False` is evaluated - Which is True, the comparison now looks like `x < True` . x being a negative number (Thus False) is indeed less than True. So the function returns True. You'd need to use braces to be explicit in order of evaluation.

Options that'd work

```
(x<0) == False
```

or

```
(x>0)
```

Comment: so what you are saying is that imageine x is -3 in this example:
the function runs and it saying: x < 0 (True) and then since that runs first it doesn't reach the comparison and just returns it?

Comment: No-  Logically Negative and 0 are False, positive numbers are True.   Firstly you are doing 0 == False, which evaluates to True, then asking is a negative number less than True, which is True. So returns True for the negative numbers

Comment: Ive updated with the explaination, if this answers your question please mark it so. thanks

Comment: "Firstly, the 0 == False is evaluated" - that's wrong. Have a look at the [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) documentation. `x < 0 == False` is a chained comparison and is evaluated as `(x < 0) and (0 == False)`.

Comment: "Negative numbers and 0 are Logically the same as False" - that's wrong too. Only `0` is a _falsey_ value. Check it with any negative number like `print(bool(-1))`.

Comment: Matthias, thanks for that, i was getting confused with the logic, please edit the answer (as its been accepted) with your explanation.